# .htaccess redirect with regex

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to set up a redirect via .htaccess as follows:

All pages from https://example.net/xyz/* should be redirected to https://example.net/abc/:

- https://example.net/xyz/foo --> https://example.net/abc/
- https://example.net/xyz/bar --> https://example.net/abc/
- https://example.net/xyz/baz --> https://example.net/abc/
- https://example.net/xyz/foo/bar/baz --> https://example.net/abc/

Would it be something like this?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xyz/ https://example.net/abc/
```

or

```
Redirect 301 ^/xyz/.* https://example.net/abc/
```

and what would be the difference?

Comment: Yes that should work. Is it not working?

Comment: i didnt try it yet. Wanted to be sure first before i break sth on the live site

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those is correct.

Redirect match should have a capturing group like:

```sh
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xyz/(.*) https://example.net/abc/$1
```

The redirect directive doesn't use regex at all. Its matches are always "starts with".  This should do what you want:

```sh
Redirect 301 /xyz https://example.net/abc
```

I would prefer to use the `Redirect` rather than the `RedirectMatch` in this case because the regex functionality is not actually needed.

As for whether it would work, you can try testing rules in simulators like https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ or you can bring up a staging server.  Testing ahead of time is a good idea, especially if there are other rules in your .htaccess file. `Redirect` directives often conflict with `RewriteRule` directives and cause unexpected behavior if you use both.

Comment: The OP would seem to be wanting to redirect to `/abc/` _only_ in all cases, not `/abc/<url>` as you would be doing here with a "capturing group". (The `RedirectMatch` directive in the question would already seem to do what the OP requires.)